# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.help' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror, python-asyncio

I am trying to make an custom help command with discord.py but I can't get past this one problem which I've been trying to get rid of for while now, but no luck.

Heres the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyHelpCommand(commands.HelpCommand):

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Bot help")
        for cog, cmds in mapping.items():
            embed.add_field(
                name=cog.qualified_name,
                value=f"{len(cmds)} commands"
            )

        channel = self.get_destination()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot._default_help_command = bot.help_command
    bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()


def teardown(bot):
    bot.help_command = bot._default_help_command
```

And heres my console output:

```py
C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\stene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bot\main.py 
[2022-11-14 15:29:12] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2022-11-14 15:29:13] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: f2fe7e6ccdc92833e5c8845196aaec88).
-----------------------------
Moderation cog has been loaded successfully!
Welcome cog has been loaded successfully!
Economy cog has been loaded successfully!
-----------------------------
Logged in as Rebellions Bot
Bot ID: 1039115327054819378
Bot verified: True
Bot created at: 2022-11-07 09:53:19.799000+00:00
-----------------------------
Failed to load extension cogs.help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bot\main.py", line 32, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 951, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.help' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Thank you!

Comment: Cog loading and teardown is async now

Answer (score 0):

async function u are can using in @commands or @bot function
True code:

```
@commands.slash_command(name='help', description='Sending bot`s help')
#its example, u can use @commands.command(alias='help')
#slash command are using only in disnake or other library
async def help(inter):
#or async def help(ctx), if u use @commands.command(alias='CommandName')

 embed = discord.Embed(title="Bot help")
        for cog, cmds in mapping.items():
            embed.add_field(
                name=cog.qualified_name,
                value=f"{len(cmds)} commands"
            )

        channel = self.get_destination()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```